# Where to see logs of print statements used in Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure Function(using Python) in which I have to browse Azure Blob Storage and calculate paths, then pass them to a Azure Synapse Data Flow. So in this function I am using 'print' statements for debugging purpose, but I am unable to see any of them.

I was expecting it to print in App Insights/logs, but of no use. I couldn't find the same anywhere.

Comment: You can see logs of your print statements after your function triggers with URL then in your terminal like here:- I used this sample code in my functions to print credentials credentials = os.environ["private_key"]

print(credentials) and it got printer after I triggered the URL in my browser in the terminal like here - https://i.imgur.com/4PNpRzM.png You can view the print statements logs in your application insights by following the steps here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#viewing-telemetry-in-monitor-tab

Comment: You can also make use of OpenCensus telemetry to log Azure functions print statements in Application insights or Log analytics log table by following the code here -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level#log-custom-telemetry

Answer (score 0):

***You can directly log the Azure Functions data to Application Insights by using Opencensus telemetry logs in your Functions code and the print statements in your code will be logged in your local terminal like below:-***

> You can refer the Opencensus Code from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration&tabs=asgi,application-level#log-custom-telemetry)

**My init.py:-**

```py
import os
import logging
import azure.functions as func

from opencensus.ext.azure import metrics_exporter
from opencensus.stats import aggregation as aggregation_module
from opencensus.stats import measure as measure_module
from opencensus.stats import stats as stats_module
from opencensus.stats import view as view_module
from opencensus.tags import tag_map as tag_map_module

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

stats = stats_module.stats
view_manager = stats.view_manager
stats_recorder = stats.stats_recorder

# Set the instrumentation key
INSTRUMENTATION_KEY = "InstrumentationKey=321ab132-a69b-4c99-8f70-c10ca8d77944;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiaeast-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiaeast.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
print(INSTRUMENTATION_KEY)
# Create a new Metrics Exporter with the Application Insights Instrumentation Key
exporter = metrics_exporter.new_metrics_exporter(connection_string=INSTRUMENTATION_KEY)

# Register the exporter
view_manager.register_exporter(exporter)

# Define your metric(s)
BLOB_COUNT_MEASURE = measure_module.MeasureInt("blob_count", "The number of blobs in the container", "unit")
BLOB_COUNT_VIEW = view_module.View("blob_count_view", "The number of blobs in the container", [], BLOB_COUNT_MEASURE, aggregation_module.CountAggregation())

# Register the view(s)
view_manager.register_view(BLOB_COUNT_VIEW)

# Define a helper function to calculate the blob count and record the metric
def get_blob_count_and_record_metric(container_name):
    try:
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['AzureWebJobsStorage'])
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
        blob_count = len(list(blob_list))
        
        mmap = stats_recorder.new_measurement_map()
        tmap = tag_map_module.TagMap()

        mmap.measure_int_put(BLOB_COUNT_MEASURE, blob_count)
        mmap.record(tmap)
        
        logging.info(f"Container {container_name} has {blob_count} blobs")
        print(container_name)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        print(container_name)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    container_name = "azure-webjobs-secrets"
    if not container_name:
        logging.error("CONTAINER_NAME environment variable not set.")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Internal Server Error",
            status_code=500
        )
    
    get_blob_count_and_record_metric(container_name)
    
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "OK",
        status_code=200
    )
```

**Local Output:-**

Function got triggered successfully and Logs were sent to Application insights, Print statements on InstrumentationKey and container_name was also printed in the terminal:-

[image]

**My Application Insights log table:-**

[image]

I deployed the Function in my Function app like below:-

[image]

***I ran the URL and the function got triggered successfully and logs got sent to application insights, Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

> ***You can check Azure Functions Monitor section referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#viewing-telemetry-in-monitor-tab) to check the HTTPResponse and message triggered by your Function app like below:-***
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> **Note- I am using logging module to log these details in my Function app terminal.**