# Azure function in app service plan triggered by service bus queue is sometimes not waking up

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-appservice

We have a function app triggered by a service bus queue.
The function app uses a basic app service plan and has `Always on` turned off.

Some time after the function runs, the job host stops and this is when the issue starts.

When a new message is queued into the service bus queue, the function sometimes wakes up and processes it properly but sometimes it does not.

Why is this happening? What's the underlying mechanism here?

The Azure documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan) did say that we should enable `always on` for the function app "to work properly" but never expounded on why and what would happen.
I read somewhere that `always on` does not affect the billing- why is `always on` allowed to be toggled off? is there a specific scenario where that is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Always On Feature keeps the underlying hosts running. In Dedicated Function app plan, Its mandatory to keep the Always On toggle to ON. Cause, This feature will keep the app loaded and running at the backend even when there's no trigger initiated from the Service Bus Function trigger. Otherwise, The Function app goes idle and it will need a Cold start, Cold start will cause a delay to load the Function trigger.

Refer this [**answer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/129584/how-can-i-keep-azure-web-app-always-on-during-a-ce) by Sneha-Agrawal-MSFT on Always ON feature.

The Always On toggle can be switched off, Cause there are requirements were the function app is not required to receive the messages frequently.

Regarding, Billing. The Function app is billed for the time the Function Trigger is running, And the Always on feature is not included in the Billing.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fully answer all the questions though.
Why does the function app sometimes get triggered properly and sometimes not? what's the underlying mechanism there?
Why is this toggle available if it's mandatory to be on?

Comment: The Function is getting triggered properly sometimes and sometimes it is not, Because once the function runs after service bus trigger. Next time it is getting cold start, If Function is not triggered for some time, Next time you trigger it, It will cause some delay. Here always on feature helps as it eliminates the cold start and runs your Function statefully. Refer this blog to understand cold start- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/#

Comment: The toggle is recommended to keep On to eliminate cold starts in your Function app so the trigger runs properly each time. There are some use cases, Where Functions Triggers are not needed to be ran regularly. There Always On feature can be set to off

Comment: the problem is the delay in processing appears to be a day, that's not what we expect from a "cold start". It's like the "cold start" is not being initiated even.

Comment: If it has a delay of 1 day, I recommend checking Azure Function logs and monitor the behaviour, Refer my answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452253/how-can-i-view-error-logs-from-a-python-azure-function-app/76453842# and you can also check the diagnostic logs by referring here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp

Comment: We already checked the logs, we can see the function getting cleaned up gracefully  with no errors on the instance that it ignores the message.

Comment: We noticed the pattern where the cold start is not being initiated when the function was triggered shortly after it was cleaned up due to inactivity.