# How to Instrument Azure Functions running on Linux App Service plan using AppDynamics?

Tags: azure-functions, appdynamics

We have a requirement to instrument azure functions hosted on App Service Plan linux using AppDynamics. There is an extension available to instrument azure functions running on Windows App Service plan as per the documentation below.

[Instrument the .NET Agent with Azure Functions](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/4.5.x/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/deploy-appdynamics-for-azure/instrument-the-net-agent-with-azure-functions)

But there is no such option available to instrument azure functions running on Linux. Are there any other solution options available for automatic instrumentation of Azure functions hosted on linux App Service Plan using AppDynamics?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**Pre-requisite**](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/4.5.x/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/deploy-appdynamics-for-azure/instrument-the-net-agent-with-azure-functions#Instrumentthe.NETAgentwithAzureFunctions-MicrosoftAzureRequirements) Only Windows OS is supported in AppDynamics. You need to raise a feature request in Cisco AppDynamics support [here](https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Cloud-Native-Application/bd-p/Cloud-Native-Application-Observability), To request support for Linux OS based Function app for AppDynamics.

*As a workaround, You can create an ARM based Function and add the AppDynamics parameters as mentioned [**here**](https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/4.5.x/en/application-monitoring/install-app-server-agents/deploy-appdynamics-for-azure/instrument-the-net-agent-with-azure-functions/automate-net-for-azure-functions-deployment).*

***In visual studio create a template of Azure Resource group and add the below code:-***

[image]

And deploy this in your Azure Web app.

Instead of using Appdynamics, One alternative is to directly use built in Azure Functions Monitoring service that comes by default. You can refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452253/how-can-i-view-error-logs-from-a-python-azure-function-app/76453842#76453842) to utilize Azure Functions Monitoring and logging.

Comment: Have you used ARM template to create AppDynamics extension to an existing function running on Unix app service plan? When I try to deploy using ARM template, I got an error  "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'AppDynamics.WindowsAzure.SiteExtension.4.5.Release' at line '1529' and column '34' is not valid. The type property is invalid. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)"