# Azure DevOps Pipeline for NodeJs Azure Function randomly fails

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-functions, puppeteer, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an **Azure DevOps Pipeline** for an **Azure Function** written in **Node.Js** and it fails sometimes, like ***3 out of 5 times it fails*** with the following error:

```
Deployment has been stopped due to SCM container restart. The restart can happen due to a management operation on site. Do not perform a management operation and a deployment operation in quick succession. Adding a small delay can help avoid any conflicts.
```

As a more context for the function, I cannot put the code for different reasons, but the function suffered some changes around ***Puppeteer*** which are used to generate some reports.

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      New-Item -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.deployment -ItemType File
      '[config] SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true' | out-file -filepath $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.deployment
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Zip source'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/source.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish zip'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/source.zip'
    ArtifactName: 'report-source'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I couldn't find anything regarding this error, and moving through the logs there isn't anything else extra.

```
    "puppeteer": "^21.3.1"
```

Edits:

1. I added `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT:1800` in Function App Configuration and no improvements.
2. I added a `'wait 30s task'` before the release step in DevOps Release and no improvements

Comment: The shared pipeline yaml doesn't contain the deploy details, how do you deploy the app? Because the error is caused by you are deploying during SCM container restart, please add some delay before the deployment, or  as @SiddheshDesai suggested, try with WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT:1800

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT yes, the release is configured in DevOps Releases with an inline PowerShell Core script:

az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $(ResourceGroup) -n $(FunctionName) --src source/source.zip --build-remote true.


Adding container start time limit doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: Please restart the app on azure and wait it to complete. Add more time delay in 'wait 30s task`, eg: 180s, you can reduce the time if it's working afterwards.  Then retry the pipeline again.

Comment: Restarting the function and a higher delay solved the issue! Thank you @wadezhou-MSFT! If you could add a proper answer to the post I will mark it as the solution, if not I'll post it

Comment: glad to know it works! I have posted the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, it could be caused by you are deploying during SCM container restart,  please restart the app on azure and wait it to complete,add some time delay, eg: 180s, you can reduce the time if it's working afterwards. Then retry the pipeline again.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve your error refer this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1342703/deployment-issues-with-python-flask-app-on-azure-w) by VenkateshDodda-MSFT > Add **`WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT:1800`** in your Function app Configuration settings like below:-

My Function app configuration settings after DevOps deployment:-

[image]

I have added pupeeteer library in my Function app by running the command below:-

```bash
npm i puppeteer
```

**My package.json:-**

```json
{
  "name": "noejsfunction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^21.3.7"
  }
}
```

**My DevOps yaml script:-**

Select below option:-

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxx-37646e944376'

 
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc43'

  
  environmentName: 'siliconfunc43'

 
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'Prepare binaries'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Functions App Deploy: siliconfunc43'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Check the Function Log stream to get more insights on the error and refer my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452253/how-can-i-view-error-logs-from-a-python-azure-function-app/76453842#76453842) to monitor your Function app and trigger and get specific insight on your error:-

[image]

Comment: I added WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT:1800 in the Function App Configuration and the issue persists