# Log errors from a Python Azure Function App?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python script running in an Azure timer function which keeps randomly failing and I am trying to figure out why. In the monitor tab, all it says is that the function failed.

I have tried logging the exception using a try-except statement but it doesn't make a difference:

```
import logging
try:
....
except Exception:
        logging.exception("Exception raised: ")
```

Comment: If you have configured the application insights while creating the functions app you can query the exceptions table to know more about the exception call stack from where it is coming from.

Comment: I deployed the function app from VS Code and there was no mention of application insights, however, I believe they are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the Azure Function App. **`Timer Trigger`** failure. ***You can query the Logs in Application insights also Log Stream in the Function app will help you diagnose your Function,*** Refer below:-

***I have added custom logging to my Function App like below:-***

**`timer_trigger:-`**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    try:
        if myTimer.past_due:
            logging.info('The timer is past due!')
        
        logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
        
        # Sample function logic: Addition of two numbers
        num1 = 5
        num2 = 10
        result = num1 + num2
        
        logging.info('Result of addition: %d', result)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Function failed with exception: %s", e)
```

**`Output:-`**

***Log Stream output:-***

**App Insights Logs:-**

[image]

**Filesystem Logs:-**

[image]

**Monitor Tab:-**

[image]

*Run query in application insights output:-*

[image]

You can query the requests table for more details on your Function execution.

***You can also check Function App> Application insights:-***

[image]

Refer my [**SO Thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452253/how-can-i-view-error-logs-from-a-python-azure-function-app/76453842#) for more details.