# how to load a registered model in azureml to a azure function app?

Tags: python, machine-learning, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am migrating to Azure function app for model inference from using Azure container instance deployment. The code below shows how I was loading the model in score.py

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from joblib import load
import os
import pathlib
from azureml.core.model import Model

def init():
    global model


def run(raw_data):

    try:
        # parse the features from the json doc
        dat = json.loads(raw_data)

        # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
        model_name = "{0}_{1}_{2}_sfsw".format(
            dat["MachineName"], dat["HeadNumber"], dat["ProductEDP"])
        model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name=model_name)
        model = load(model_path)
```

How would I load the model in a azure function app. would in be in the same way? is def init():
global model still required? the following is code for azure function python app

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import joblib
from azureml.core.model import Model



def main(req: func.HttpRequest):
    logging.info("Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.")

    try:
        # Check if request contains JSON
        if not req.get_json():
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "JSON data expected in request.",
                status_code=400
            )
        dat = req.get_json()

    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Invalid JSON received.",
            status_code=400
        )

    # Load the model
    try:
        # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
        model_name = "{0}_{1}_{2}_sfsw".format(
            dat["MachineName"], dat["HeadNumber"], dat["ProductEDP"])
        model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name=model_name)
        model = joblib.load(model_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Model '{model_name}' not found.",
            status_code=404
        )
```

Comment: the def init(): global model is called when the container is initialized/started, typically after create/update of the deployment. I assume this is not required if your deploying models  in a function app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Muhammad Pathan you are not required to define global model variable in this function. You can update your code like below:-

***I tweaked your code to  load my model and perform inference:-***

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model
import joblib
import pandas as pd

def load_model(model_name):
    try:
        # Load the model from Azure ML
        model = Model(workspace=ws, name=model_name)
        model_path = model.download(exist_ok=True)  # Download the model
        loaded_model = joblib.load(model_path)
        return loaded_model
    except Exception as e:
        return None

# Load your Azure ML Workspace from a configuration file
ws = Workspace.from_config('./config.json')

def main(req: func.HttpRequest):
    logging.info("Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.")

    try:
        # Check if request contains JSON
        if not req.get_json():
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "JSON data expected in the request.",
                status_code=400
            )
        dat = req.get_json()
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Invalid JSON received.",
            status_code=400
        )

    model_name = "sample_model3"  # Replace with the model name in your workspace

    # Load the model
    model = load_model(model_name)
    if model is None:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Model '{model_name}' not found.",
            status_code=404
        )

    # Perform inference using the loaded model
    try:
        result = model.predict(pd.DataFrame([dat]))
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Inference result: {result}")
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred during inference: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***Postman request with JSON body:-
Json request body according to my model:-***

```json
{
    "sepal length (cm)": 5.1,
    "sepal width (cm)": 3.5,
    "petal length (cm)": 1.4,
    "petal width (cm)": 0.2
}
```

**Postman Output:-**

[image]
*As an alternative*, In order to **load your Azure ML model** you can make **use of** the **HttpTrigger code** below:-

I have **loaded and downloaded the model in a folder called temp. This folder is also created by Function code in the same directory as my Function code** with **Azure Functions** like below:-

Make sure you have logged into your Azure account which contains your ML workspace and model with **`az login`** command in your VS code Terminal for the below Function code to work.

**My HttpTrigger code:-**

```py
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model

# Function to load and download models
def load_and_download_models():
    try:
        ws = Workspace.from_config('./config.json')
        # Load your Azure ML Workspace. Replace with your own values.
        ws = Workspace(subscription_id="xxxxxxxxaxxxx",
                       resource_group="xxxx",
                       workspace_name="xxx")

        
        downloaded_models_path = "temp"

        loaded_and_downloaded_models = []

        for model_name in ws.models:
            # Iterate through model names in the workspace

            # Load the model using its name
            model = Model(ws, model_name)

            

            # Download the model to a specified directory
            model_path = model.download(target_dir=downloaded_models_path)

            loaded_and_downloaded_models.append(model_name)

        return loaded_and_downloaded_models

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

# Azure Function entry point with HTTP trigger
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        loaded_and_downloaded_models = load_and_download_models()
        if isinstance(loaded_and_downloaded_models, list):
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Models loaded and downloaded successfully: {', '.join(loaded_and_downloaded_models)}", status_code=200)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {loaded_and_downloaded_models}", status_code=500)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Python Azure function timer trigger log info not showing when deployed - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307604/python-azure-function-timer-trigger-log-info-not-showing-when-deployed/77308937#77308937)