# How to check various times in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In Azure Durable Functions, I would like to measure **the time taken to transfer data in activity and orchestration functions** and **the response time of activity functions**.

I think I can check this from Application Insights in the Azure Portal, but I am having trouble with the many options available.

How can I check such response and transfer times from the Azure portal?

It would be helpful if you could provide me with a picture.

Comment: You may utilize the tracking events that the Azure Functions Durable Extension emits to measure the time it takes to transport data in activity and orchestration functions. The Application Insights Analytics feature in the Azure site can be used to locate and query these tracking events- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-diagnostics.md

Comment: To measure the response time of activity functions, you can use the Profiler feature of Application Insights. You can enable the Profiler on your Azure Functions app and view the data in the Profiler for your Functions app -https://i.imgur.com/oxXmrPP.png - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-azure-functions.md

Comment: I am concerned that I am getting the information correctly as my primary language is not English.

What I did was add logLevel to host.json, and add DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION and APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION.

Are there any other steps needed to check transfer time or startup time besides this?

Comment: I am concerned that I am getting the information correctly as my primary language is not English. What I did was add logLevel to host.json, and add DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION and APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION. Are there any other steps needed to check transfer time or startup time besides this? > These are the correct steps to get the performance anamolies and to get the transfer and startup time

Comment: One more method I can think of is to use OpenTelemetry where you can use OpenTelemetry, opencensus to calculate the Transfer and starup time locally and send this data to your Application insights for monitoring, Refer my SO thread answer here wher I have used Opentelemetry/opencensus to send custom data in azure functions- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225763/where-to-see-logs-of-print-statements-used-in-python-azure-function/76227708#76227708 application insights-

Comment: For opentelemetry Refer this -https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable.md For opencensus refer my answer above

Comment: It's complicated and I don't understand it yet, but will we be able to see the time taken for the transfer and the instance startup time in milliseconds?

Comment: The Profiler feature was mentioned as being available for the App Service plan, but it turns out that I cannot use it because I am using the Consumption plan.

Comment: It's complicated and I don't understand it yet, but will we be able to see the time taken for the transfer and the instance startup time in milliseconds? > Yes, Just need to write the code to send the time taken and instance startup time in ms with opencensus package to app insights. I'll update you on the same

Comment: The Profiler feature was mentioned as being available for the App Service plan, but it turns out that I cannot use it because I am using the Consumption plan.  > Yes, There are few restrictions with consumption based plan

Comment: Let me confirm a last point.
To summarize what we have said so far, to get the relationship between transfer size and time, run a query in Application Insights.
To check the startup time of an instance, use OpenTelemetry.
Am I correct in this understanding?

Comment: Yes, Or create a custom function code to get the above metrics with Open telemetry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code in My Azure Durable Functions to receive transfer time and Response time like below:-

**My function_app.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import time

myApp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/{functionName}")
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def http_start(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    function_name = req.route_params.get('functionName')
    instance_id = await client.start_new(function_name, None)  # Pass the functionName here
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response

# Orchestrator
@myApp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def hello_orchestrator(context):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    
    result1 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Seattle")
    response_time1 = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result2 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "Tokyo")
    response_time2 = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    result3 = yield context.call_activity("hello", "London")
    response_time3 = time.perf_counter() - start_time

    print(f"Response time for Seattle: {response_time1} seconds")
    print(f"Response time for Tokyo: {response_time2} seconds")
    print(f"Response time for London: {response_time3} seconds")

    return [result1, result2, result3]

# Activity
@myApp.activity_trigger(input_name="city")
def hello(city: str):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    # Your activity function logic
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    
    transfer_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Transfer time for {city}: {transfer_time} seconds")

    return "Hello " + city
```

**Output:-**

[image]

I deployed this Function in my Azure Function app and copied the Function URL and called the Http_orchestrator from the browser with Function URL like below. I received the Transfer Time and Response Time correctly in the Log stream and Application Insights like below:-

URL:- **`https://function-app-name.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/hello_orchestrator`**

**Output:-**

**Browser:-**

[image]

Log Stream Output giving Response Time and Transfer Time successfully like below:-

[image]

[image]

**Output Logs in Application Insights:-**

```
traces
```

**Response Time:-**

[image]

**Transfer Time:-**

[image]