# How to enter a query to get response times in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I want to send HTTP requests with Azure Functions and measure the response time of each request.

I believe I can check the response time for each request in the logs in the Applications Insights in the Azure Portal. So I entered the query shown in the image. Then I was able to check the response time.

[image]

However, I cannot see which points received what HTTP parameters.

**Can you please give me a query that will show me the response time so that I can see the details of each request?**

Ideally, if I click on a point in the scatterplot, it would display the parameters given in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer so [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77378773/20238030), Follow the below steps.

Create custom telemetry events in your Azure Functions code and log the relevant information to view the details of each request, including the HTTP parameters, in Azure Application Insights.

```py
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> str:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    response = await client.start_new(
        orchestrator_function_name="MyOrchestrator",
        instance_id=None,
        input=req.params.get('param1'),  # You can pass parameters as input
    )
    
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, response)

# Orchestrator function
def MyOrchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    req_data = context.get_input()  # Retrieve the parameter

    # Log custom telemetry event with the parameter
    custom_properties = {
        "Parameter1": req_data,
        # Add more parameters as needed
    }
    context.set_custom_status(custom_properties)

    # Your orchestration logic here

    # Example: call an activity function
    result = yield context.call_activity("MyActivity", req_data)
    
    # Your orchestration logic continues here

    return result

# Activity function
def MyActivity(context: df.DurableActivityContext, input_data):
    # Log custom telemetry event in the activity function
    custom_properties = {
        "ActivityParameter": input_data,
        # Add more properties as needed
    }
    context.set_custom_status(custom_properties)

    # Your activity logic here

    return f"Activity completed with parameter: {input_data}"
```

- Include the HTTP parameters you want to log as custom properties in the `properties` dictionary.
- Use query like the following to retrieve response times and HTTP parameters:

```
customEvents
| where name == "FunctionRequest"
| extend ResponseTime = toreal(customDimensions["ResponseTime"])
| project timestamp, ResponseTime, Parameter1 = tostring(customDimensions["Parameter1"]), Parameter2 = tostring(customDimensions["Parameter2"])
```

- Running this query in Application Insights Analytics will give you a table of data that includes the timestamp, response time, and the HTTP parameters you logged.

[image]

Comment: Is [name == "FunctionRequest"] in the query an item that is automatically created even if it is not set in the code?

Comment: [name == "FunctionRequest"] filter in the query is not something that is automatically created by your code. Instead, it is a part of the query that filters log entries based on the name field in your log data.

Comment: I could not find the data, as if [name == "FunctionRequest"] does not apply in my environment." Where can I get the "name" from?

Comment: it's set in your Azure Functions, reviewing your telemetry and logging configuration in your code and Azure portal settings should help you identify the correct field to use in your query.